# twisted loopingcall access class vars

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following example

```
class Intake:
    def __init__(self):

        #
        # aggregate dict to store all the counters
        #
        self.counters = {}

        #
        # start a looping call to run reach minute
        #
        self.lc = task.LoopingCall(self.aggregate, self.counters)
        self.lc.start(60)


    def aggregate(self, counters):
        print counters
```

So that works just fine.. but in my aggregate function I need to clear out the self.counters dict. I'm having issues doing this..

I want to do something like

```
    def aggregate(self, counters):
        print counters

        self.counters = {}
```

If I reference self.counters in that function I get

```
exceptions.AttributeError: Intake instance has no attribute 'counters'
```

Comment: ... so what is the question? Does that not work?

Comment: I edited the question to add the error at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to include a runnable example of your problem, if I try what you describe it works fine.

```
from twisted.internet import task

class Intake:
    def __init__(self):

        #
        # aggregate dict to store all the counters
        #
        self.counters = {}
        self.count = 0
        #
        # start a looping call to run reach minute
        #
        self.lc = task.LoopingCall(self.aggregate, self.counters)
        self.lc.start(1)


    def aggregate(self, counters):
        print '%d, %r, %r' % (self.count, counters, self.counters)
        self.count += 1
        self.counters = {}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    r = Intake()
    reactor.run()
```